# How do I get the active dialog object inside an Activity on Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, dialog

I'm trying to retrieve an AlertDialog object that is active at top of the activity for unit testing purposes. My objective is to check if the dialog being shown is the correct one. If it has its strings showing correctly, for example.

I know that its not a good practice and not what unit testing is intended to do, but I`m curious if It can be done.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: why can't you just make a field private to your activity and access it through getters?

Comment: I can, but I dont want to change the source code being tested.

Comment: @Tejaswi Yerukalapudi I haven't found the solution, but I started using a blackbox testing framework called [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium), with which you can search for **any** text string displayed on the activity. So I'm asserting if I match that text the alert is supposed to display, and if so, I'm considering that the correct dialog is showing up.

Comment: @Tejaswi Yerukalapudi I haven't tested yet. But there's another framework called [Robolectric](http://http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric) which has a method `ShadowAlertDialog.getLastestAlertDialog()` that returns a Dialog.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I was looking at Robotium as well, but decided to go with Google's version of jUnit for now.